# Fake store API returns 524

Tags: python, api, python-requests, response

I've found [this api](https://fakestoreapi.com/docs) and tried to test it's "login user" feature with this code:

```
import requests

url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/auth/login"
data = {'login': "mor_2314", 'password': "83r5^_"}

result = requests.post(url, json=data)

print(result)
```

the request takes a lot of time to go through and after that It prints <response [524]>, not a token as shown in the documentation,

is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

`'login'` should be `'username'` in your `data` payload.

```
>>> data = {'username': "mor_2314", 'password': "83r5^_"}
>>> result = requests.post(url, json=data)
>>> print(result)
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: that's a silly mistake, thanks tho :D

Comment: just to add: the token will then be in ``result.json()``